# How to add corners to a view

Tags: android

I added a full border around a view but I need to add just the corner as shown image below :

[image]

**I mean the red corner only .**

I tried to adjust the below border xml , but it didn't work :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="10dp" android:height="10dp" android:color="#B22222" /> 
    <solid android:color="#FCE6C9" /> 
    <corners android:radius="20dp"  /> 
</shape>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do this using a `ShapeDrawable`, as it would require you to use some sort of margin or padding on the drawable itself. There actually is a `padding` attribute, but unfortunately that only has effect on the content of the `View`, and not the drawable itself.

That being said, an easy solution would be to create a 9-patch in stead and apply that as background to the `TextView`. Just for demonstration purposes: make the 9-patch look somewhat like this:

[image: Red rounded corner 9-patch example]

---

**Edit:**
On second thought, there's actually another option that relies on using a `LayerDrawable` to create the desired effect. It's a bit tedious to create and I have my doubts it'll be more efficient than using a 9-patch, but at least you don't have to render out images, which means that if you need to make e.g. a change in colours, it's more straightforward.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:left="30dp"
        android:right="30dp" />
    <item android:bottom="30dp" android:drawable="@android:color/white"
        android:top="30dp" />
    <item android:bottom="30dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp"
        android:drawable="@color/pink" android:top="30dp" />
    <item android:bottom="10dp" android:left="30dp" android:right="30dp"
        android:drawable="@color/pink" android:top="10dp" />

</layer-list>
```

Some details: `@drawable/rounded` is the code snippet you posted yourself. The following two items are simply white rectangles with an offset, to create the white edges. Now, since these will also overlay the pink surface, we need two more pink rectangles (again with specific offsets) to counter that. The result is a background that looks exactly like what you're showing in your question.

Note that you might want to see if you can optimise this a bit. At the least I'd recommend not hardcoding the offsets (like I did for simplicity), but store them in a `dimens.xml` file so you can keep these values centralized and consistent by referencing them from both the `ShapeDrawable` and `LayerDrawable`.

**Addendum:** On pre-ICS (or perhaps pre-Honeycomb) devices, there appears to be an issue with directly referencing colours with the `android:drawable` attribute. You can however easily get around this by setting up another drawable (be it either a 9-patch or `ShapeDrawable`) to represent this colour. For example, in the snippet above, you would replace `android:drawable="@color/pink"` with `android:drawable="@drawable/color_pink"`, where `color_pink` can simply be an xml file containing:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FCE6C9" /> 
</shape>
```

Obviously you will need to do the same for all other colours referenced in the `LayerDrawable`. Tested on Gingerbread 2.3.7.

Comment: thanks for your answer , but i apply your code just gave me pink background without border , also i refer ( @drawable/rounded) as i understand you to shape code that i already post it in my question

Comment: Interesting. I initially tested the drawable on my Galaxy Nexus and that worked flawlessly. After your comment I also tried it on a Gingerbread device and noticed the same issue you describe. There seems to be a problem with directly referencing colours as drawables. Please see the addendum to my answer for a simple workaround. With that approach, the drawable also showed up correctly on my older device. Hope that helps.

Comment: check update image above ,sorry previous image was edited wrong in photo editor , also i applayed your updated code but i cant get it .

Comment: @AndroidStack: Just to get things straight: you're after coloured corners with transparent gaps inbetween? In that case I don't think there's a way to 'fake' the gaps using xml. I suggest you either create your own extension of `TextView` to take care of the drawing, or use a 9-patch, as suggested earlier (simply change the white gaps to be transparent).

Answer (score 0):

I would create a 9-patch file and set it to be the background of the main container. The steps to do that would be.

1. You create the background you would like roughly in fireworks, illustrator, or whatever image editing software you prefer.
2. Then crop the artwork so that there is only a 1 pixel border around the artwork. Save it as a png.
3. Open the draw9patch.bat file in your android sdk folder on your computer C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools.
4. Open your png file. You can then use your mouse to click on the outer 1 pixel border which will turn the clicked pixels black. The areas that you have black pixels on both the top and bottom or on the left and right will be the area that is stretched. In your case you just want to have the middle area where there is no red stretched.
5. My personal preference is to just open the file above and save it as a 9 patch file. Then open it in my photo editing software to create a 1 pixel thick line in the same fashion as above. It is quicker and more precise.
6. Finally add the file to your drawable folder. Then set the background of your main view container to the drawable.

That should be it. Hope that helps.